# А дальше всё(,) как пишут в книгах: Мир обесцвечен и очень мал

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

А дальше всё(,) как пишут в книгах:
Мир обесцвечен и очень мал.

Нужна ли тут запятая?
Слово "всё" меня смущает, из-за него смысл не могу понять. Здесь не имеется в виду "всё будет, как пишут в книгах". Здесь именно пояснение слова "всё" после двоеточия идет.

Comment: еще пример: Всё(,) как ты сказал.

Comment: Чегриз, уточните вопрос. Вас интересует значение слова "всё" или только запятая после него? Двоеточие относится ко всему обороту   обороту "всё, как пишут в книгах", не к одному слову всё.

Comment: behemothus, меня интересует запятая. Есть куча сходных предложений: дальше всё как пишут в книгах; всё как пишут в книгах (менее распространённое); всё как у людей; всё как ты сказал; всё как ты скажешь (=всё будет). "Как" здесь выступает как наречие в значении "таким же образом, так же". Но если добавить  "так" (Всё так, как пишут в книгах), то "так" будет наречием, а "как" уже союзом.

Comment: ...Нет, не союзом.  Союзным словом.

Comment: А дальше (БУДЕТ, СТАЛО, ВЫШЛО) всё(,) как пишут в книгах. Не оказалось сказуемого, а оно может уйти только оставив вместо себя ТИРЕ: А дальше – всё, как пишут в книгах

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу смысла. 
Здесь именно *"будет"/"есть", как пишут в книгах*. Почему вас двоеточие напугало, не знаю.

После него идет раскрытие смысла, т.е. именно то, что (по мнению автора) пишут в книгах. Не зная контекста, можно предположить, например, такое:

Сейчас мир цветной и большой. Что-то произойдет: война, катастрофа. И дальше ***всё пойдёт так, как пишут*** в книгах: мир станет маленьким и серым... В тексте (стихах?) все лишнее слова убраны, осталось то, что вы процитировали.

Что вас напугало, не знаю.

Запятая нужна. Да она в любом случае нужна, как ни трактуй...